# Export to CSV from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am exporting data from SQL Server to a CSV file.

So, I have a column which has a single digit and double digit values. When the output has a single value column I am trying to append a **0** in front to make it standard as double digit. But when I create CSV through **master.dbo.xp_cmdshell** command it removes the **0** in the CSV file and passes as a single digit. I have tried every possible string function of SQL Server to append that 0.

For Ex: **Column A** has a value as **9**. I try to append a **0** which makes it as **09** and it works fine the Grid-Result but as soon as I export it to CSV through bcp command it just comes as **9** and not **09**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimum reproducible example? How are you actually testing the CSV output - in Notepad or Excel? Excel, of course, will try to apply its own formatting and will interpret numeric-looking things as numbers.

Comment: I am testing it in Notepad. But it is the same.